# Object passed in request returned as a string ([object Object])

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi so I am trying to pass an object to my request URL, however while using the variables in req.query, I can see that the object is getting converted to a string and being returned as [object Object] instead of the object.

```
const object = {'itemA':1, 'itemB':1};
query = `field=${fieldToReturn}`
```

Now while retrieving it

```
let field = req.query.field;
console.log(field) //returns [object Object] instead of the object itself.
console.log(JSON.stringify(field)) //also returns [object Object]
```

Comment: You did not add the code how you convert object to fieldToReturn. Besides that you shouldn't pass JSON as a query paramater. 
I would suggest to pass the JSON data in the body as a POST request.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an object in request params by first stringifying and adding it in params and after retrieving it in server parse it to get object back.

```js
const object = {'itemA':1, 'itemB':1};
query = `field=${JSON.stringify(fieldToReturn)}`

let field = req.query.field;
console.log(field) //will log stringified object
console.log(JSON.parse(field)) // will log it as object
```